# Add Category / Label to Pandas Multi-Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to add a row with a unique timestamp ('t') to the following Multiindex I've tried using code which I found here on Stack Overflow

```
dfMaster.loc[('USD/CHF', '2021-02-17 15:29:00'), :] = ('0.89226',  '0.89557',  '0.89210',  '0.89210')
                                   o        h        l        c
cp      t                                                      
USD/CHF 2021-02-16 17:27:00  0.89231  0.89499  0.89210  0.89236
        2021-02-16 17:28:00  0.89226  0.89557  0.89210  0.89210
        2021-02-16 17:29:00  0.89239  0.89573  0.89210  0.89225
        2021-02-16 17:30:00  0.89215  0.89226  0.89190  0.89190
        2021-02-16 17:31:00  0.89216  0.89562  0.89200  0.89220
```

I receive this error message
KeyError: "['2024-02-16 15:29:00'] not in index"

How do I add the new timestamp to the multiindex (without removing and re adding the index)

What I want is this:

```
                                   o        h        l        c
cp      t                                                      
USD/CHF 2021-02-16 17:27:00  0.89231  0.89499  0.89210  0.89236
        2021-02-16 17:28:00  0.89226  0.89557  0.89210  0.89210
        2021-02-16 17:29:00  0.89239  0.89573  0.89210  0.89225
        2021-02-16 17:30:00  0.89215  0.89226  0.89190  0.89190
        2021-02-16 17:31:00  0.89216  0.89562  0.89200  0.89220
        2021-02-17 15:29:00  0.89226  0.89557  0.89210  0.89210
```

Comment: This works for me on pandas 1.2, can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for the quick response, I was using Pandas 1.2.2 but rolled it back in case it was a newly introduced bug but still have the same error.